# Can't suspend laptop using systemd while Slack is started

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, suspend

Sometimes when I'm trying to suspend a laptop using `systemctl hybrid-sleep`, I get response like this:

`Failed to put system into hybrid sleep via logind: Sleep verb not supported`

But after reboot everything is ok - it just works. 
The version of systemd I'm using is v227.

---

UPDATE:

I found out what was the problem with. It's the **Slack** built from AUR, what prevents the system to sleep.

I don't know, why it happens, cause `systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block` shows me

`0 inhibitors listed.`

Comment: Do you have a swap partition and/or is it enabled & mounted at the time of the command?

Comment: @SnowRep Yes, I have swap partition and it's in use at the time of command. But it's in use even when it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in **Slack** from AUR (package slack-desktop) that's somehow preventing logind to sleep